# Java: what is the class for the isBinary-method?

Tags: java, class, binary, methods

I am accustomed to java.io.* and java.util.* but not to the tree:

```
com.starbase.util
Class FileUtils

java.lang.Object

  |

  +--com.starbase.util.FileUtils
```

[Source.](http://techpubs.borland.com/starteam/2006/en/SDKDocs/api/com/starbase/util/FileUtils.html)

So which class should I import to use the isBinary-method? Do I do "import java.lang.Object;" or "import java.lang.Object.com.starbase.util.FileUtils;"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would do `import com.starbase.util.FileUtils;` or `import static com.starbase.util.FileUtils.*`. The hierarchy is just showing that the class `FileUtils` extends `Object` (as do all classes).

You do also have to have the .jar file/API to access this class.

**EDIT**: Added possible standalone implementation:

If you want to implement this yourself (I noticed your own 'trivial' answer), you could do something like this:

```
    public static boolean isBinary(String fileName) throws IOException {
        return isBinary(new File(fileName));
    }

    public static boolean isBinary(File file) throws IOException {
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
        try {
            byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
            int bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = is.read(buf)) >= 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < bytesRead; i++) {
                    if (buf[i] == (byte) 0)
                        return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        } finally {
            is.close();
        }
    }
```

Please note, I have not tested this.

I should add that this is the trivial implementation. There are many kinds of text files that would be considered binary with this. If you were to allow text to be Unicode and/or UTF-8 (or other text encoding) then this quickly becomes very difficult. Then you need to develop some kinds of heuristics to differentiate between the kinds of files and this would not be 100% accurate. So, it really depends on what you are trying to do with this.

Answer (score 1):

`com.starbase.util.FileUtils` is not in the standard packaged Java SDK, but instead the [**StarTeam SDK**](http://techpubs.borland.com/starteam/2009/en/SDK_Documentation/guide/index.html) which you would need to download in order to use the [`FileUtils#isBinary`](http://techpubs.borland.com/starteam/2006/en/SDKDocs/api/com/starbase/util/FileUtils.html#isBinary%28java.io.File%29) method.

Once installed, you would just need to add:

```
import com.starbase.util.FileUtils;
```

However, if you do not want to use a third-party SDK, let us know how `isBinary` would be helpful to you and we could find a standard Java equivalent.

Also to clarify, `import.java.lang.Object.com.starbase.util.FileUtils` is not a valid import, you are concatenating two different packages together.

It has to be either `import java.lang.Object` or `import com.starbase.util.FileUtils`.

Comment: looking totally trivial impl. to know whether a file is binary, the purpose is not to make parser.

Comment: As far as I know, there isn't an easy way to check if a file is binary, I have never used the StarTeam SDK, but if they have what you need, try it out and see what results you get.

Answer (score 1):

You never have to import java.lang.Object, it's imported implicitely and is the class that every other class is derived from. When you import another class, you import it based on the package it's in. So for the class you want to use it would be:

```
import com.starbase.util.FileUtils;
```

Answer (score 0):

Totally trivial and perhaps easiest but very unreliable!

```
if( filename.toLowerCase().trim().endsWith(".bin"))
     return "Binary";
```

Comment: That assumes the file name really matches the content, but there are a lot of other kinds of files that can be binary. The `isBinary` method in that API would be checking some of the content to differentiate between binary and text.

Comment: I reread the API javadoc you reference and it states "The definition of binary is that the file has at least one null (0x0) character." So it opens and scans the file and if it finds a byte that is 0x0 binary, it considers it a binary file.